# Image Gallery slidedown text - with style="visibility: hidden can´t make it work

Tags: jquery, hidden, slide

I'm doing an image gallery, on mouseover a text slides down from an image.
My problem is that my text div (`#portText-`) has a `style="visibility: hidden;"` and I don't know how to add this to the code.

This is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).on("ready", function ()
{
  $('.moreInfo').hover(    
    function() {
      var myId= "#portText-" + $(this).data('id');
      (myId).slideDown(200).delay(2000);
    },
    function() {
      var myId= "#portText-" + $(this).data('id');
      $(myId).slideUp(2000);
    }
  );
}); 
</script>
```

My body:

```
<div class="unidad">      

  <div class="moreInfo" data-id="1">
    <img src="img/01/rotate.php" height="417" width="550" border="none">
  </div>

  <div class="portText" id="portText-1" style="visibility: hidden;">

    <table class="resumen" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> <br>
          Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text Lorem Ipsum text<br>
          <p><a  href="mb01.html" target="_self"><strong>mas info</strong></a></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you change `visibility: hidden` to `display: none` then the `.slideDown()` should properly display the div.

Comment: Thank you very much for your generosity!

Comment: I was about to share this!